# Does a Facebook application's app id expire?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have app id to access facebook app page, I want to know that is there any expiration of APP id(as it there is an expiry for access token) in facebook graph api or it will remain same forever?
Thanks in advance

Comment: facebook app id won't expire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Facebook App IDs don't expire, only the access tokens do.